# How to emulate a tty port from a GPSD stream

Tags: java, nmea, gpsd

I would like to ask my previous question in a more refined way...
This is the problem:
I have a GPS receiver, in a vehicle, and need to be able to share its NMEA text strings with various clients on the LAN.

We would like to do this over the LAN, so I don't have to build an analog RS-232 distribution system.

The GPS interface is currently connected to /dev/ttyAMA0 on an RPi2, which is running an NTP server, and a GPSD server. (It is also handling 1 PPS from the GPS receiver, and provides a 10 MHz GPS disciplined time standard.)

I can not find a client anywhere that receives a GPSD TCP stream and converts it back to NMEA data.

Does something already exist?

In the alternative, I was going to write a client in Java to do this task, and am looking for suggestions as to the best way to approach this.

Thank you in advance,
John

This is what I have done:

cgps 192.168.56.28:2947

and the NMEA data is converted to a screen readable display.

Buy what I need is for it to be in the form of a tty device file, such as /dev/ttyGPSD, or something that I can pass as a parameter to the various devices that need to see the GPS NMEA data.

Comment: *do this over the LAN, so I don't have to build an analog RS-232 distribution* Actually, that's a [thing](https://www.tindie.com/products/theoldnet/rs232-serial-wifi-modem-for-vintage-computers-v4/). (There are [several](https://hackaday.com/2021/04/18/diy-wireless-serial-adapter-speaks-true-rs-232/), you should shop around). But your current approach seems reasonable for ntp.

Comment: Why use GPSD at all?  Why not just pipe that serial port over a network port?